# Phonegap Android Application crash

Tags: cordova

I am trying to insert around 900 base64 images in database using Phonegap brodysoft Sqlite Plugin. It's working but after 100 data my app crash.Please give me any solution. I am really very frustrated  due to this.

Console log of Android App

```
10-08 14:11:17.351: I/v8(10288): <--- JS stacktrace --->
10-08 14:11:17.351: I/v8(10288): ==== JS stack trace =========================================
10-08 14:11:17.351: I/v8(10288): Security context: 0x3480e829 <String[7]: file://>
10-08 14:11:17.351: I/v8(10288):     1: Join(aka Join) [native array.js:133] [pc=0x26f6fe3c] (this=0x41d080dd <undefined>,o=0x948fff29 <JS Array[600581]>,v=600581,C=0x41d08159 <String[0]: >,B=0x41d6d335 <JS Function ConvertToString (SharedFunctionInfo 0x41d37dbd)>)
10-08 14:11:17.351: I/v8(10288):     2: InnerArrayJoin(aka InnerArrayJoin) [native array.js:331] [pc=0x26f4b298] (this=0x41d080dd <undefined>,C=0x41d08159 <String[0]: >,o=0x948fff29 <JS Array[...
10-08 14:11:17.746: W/google-breakpad(10288): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
10-08 14:11:17.746: W/google-breakpad(10288): Chrome build fingerprint:
10-08 14:11:17.746: W/google-breakpad(10288): 0.0.1
10-08 14:11:17.746: W/google-breakpad(10288): 1
10-08 14:11:17.746: W/google-breakpad(10288): 3287cb47-323f-452a-9071-08e954855982
10-08 14:11:17.746: W/google-breakpad(10288): ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
10-08 14:11:17.746: A/libc(10288): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xfbadbeef in tid 10338 (Thread-5515)
```

Comment: Hello, Krishna vrinsoft you are use pagination ? in your application.

Comment: No I am not using any pagination in App. I just store images in Database and whenever offline show images from database with flip. It's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

@Krishna,
the error you got `fault addr 0xfbadbeef` seemed very strange to me. So I looked it up. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak)

> 0xFBADBEEF ("bad beef") is used in the WebKit and Blink layout engines to indicate a known, unrecoverable error such as out of memory

This indicate you either:

1. you are NOT releasing your memory properly, or
2. this is a bug with the webview library, or
3. this is a sqlite plugin bug.

Best of Luck

Comment: Okay.Thanks. I think it's memory issue.